# Why are daily returns all zeros using Quantmod?

Tags: r, xts, quantmod

I used the following code:

```
getSymbols(c("TSLA", "AAPL", "CSCO", "IBM"))
tsla<-TSLA['2022-01-03::2023-01-03']
aapl=AAPL['2022-01-03::2023-01-03']
csco=CSCO['2022-01-03::2023-01-03']
ibm=IBM['2022-01-03::2023-01-03']

tsla<-tsla$TSLA.Adjusted
aapl<-aapl$AAPL.Adjusted
csco<-csco$CSCO.Adjusted
ibm<-ibm$IBM.Adjusted
stkdata=cbind(tsla, aapl, csco, ibm)

n<-length(stkdata[,1])
rets<-log(stkdata[2:n,]/stkdata[1:(n-1),])
```

It produces all zeros.

After I assigned stkdata[2:n] to x and stkdata[1:n-1] to y, R shows

> x[1,]

```
           TSLA.Adjusted AAPL.Adjusted CSCO.Adjusted IBM.Adjusted
2022-01-04      383.1967      178.3907      59.26239     129.9028
```

> y[1,]

```
           TSLA.Adjusted AAPL.Adjusted CSCO.Adjusted IBM.Adjusted
2022-01-03      399.9267      180.6839      60.75242     128.0392
```

This is fine. But

> x[1,]/y[1,]

```
Data:
numeric(0)

Index:
Date of length 0
```

What could be the problem? Thanks ahead!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** `getSymbols` can place the results into a local environment and then we can iterate over its elements using `eapply`.  Then use `diff` with `arithmetic=FALSE` causing `diff` to perform division rather than subtraction.

If x is the ratio of the current price to the prior price then
while it is true that log(x) approximately equals x-1 if the return is small we don't really need to use that approximation and can calculate the return exactly using x-1.

Regarding the question, xts objects do not combine by position but by time. Removing the first or last element of an xts object does not change the times so the code in the question is dividing `stkdata` by itself except for the positions on the end which have been removed.

Try the code below.

```
library(quantmod)

tickers <- c("TSLA", "AAPL", "CSCO", "IBM")
getSymbols(tickers, env = e <- new.env(), from = "2022-01-03", to = "2023-01-03")
stks <- do.call("merge", eapply(e, Ad))
rets <- diff(stks, arithmetic = FALSE) - 1
```

**2)** A variation is to use `getSymbols` to load the data into the current R workspace, as in the question, and then use `mget`.

This assumes that the name of the object created for each ticker symbol is the same as the input symbol and while that is usually true it is not for symbols such as `^SPX` which contain a special character. In that case use solution (1) above, which will always work, or create a suitably modified version of `tickers` to use with `mget`.  For example, if we have `tickers <- "^IXIC"` then use `tickers.out <- sub("\\^", "", tickers); mget(tickers.out)` in the code below.

```
library(quantmod)

tickers <- c("TSLA", "AAPL", "CSCO", "IBM")
getSymbols(tickers, from = "2022-01-03", to = "2023-01-03")
stks <- do.call("merge", lapply(mget(tickers), Ad))
rets <- diff(stks, arithmetic = FALSE) - 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I chose the second one. It worked. Your codes were much more concise too. By the way, does "Ad" in do.call mean Adjusted? R actually accepts abbreviation?

Comment: The quantmod package has convenience functions for extracting columns from financial market data. Take a look at `help("OHLC", package = "quantmod")`.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is expected because arithmetic and logical operations on xts objects are done on observations that have the same date.

You should use the `lag()` function to change the datetime index alignment. `log(stkdata / lag(stkdata))`.

Note that you have to be *very* careful using `lag()` with dplyr loaded. It breaks how base R's `lag()` function is supposed to work, which breaks `lag(my_xts)`. It also breaks `lag()` on all other types of objects that have their own `lag()` method (e.g. zoo).

Comment: Your warning made me cautious using lag(). Thank you for your reply and warning.

Comment: You can use `stats::lag()` if you want to be certain that you're not using `dplyr::lag()`

Answer (score -2):

With `tidyquant` you can calculate daily log returns as such:

```
library(tidyquant)
library(tidyverse)

df = tq_get(c("TSLA", "AAPL", "CSCO", "IBM"),
         from = "2022-01-03",
         to = "2023-01-04")

log_return = df %>% 
  group_by(symbol) %>% 
  tq_mutate(select = adjusted, 
            mutate_fun = periodReturn, 
            period = "daily", 
            type = "log", 
            col_rename = "log_returns") 

# A tibble: 1,008 × 9
# Groups:   symbol [4]
   symbol date        open  high   low close    volume adjusted log_returns
   <chr>  <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>       <dbl>
 1 TSLA   2022-01-03  383.  400.  379.  400. 103931400     400.     0      
 2 TSLA   2022-01-04  397.  403.  374.  383. 100248300     383.    -0.0427 
 3 TSLA   2022-01-05  382.  390.  360.  363.  80119800     363.    -0.0550 
 4 TSLA   2022-01-06  359   363.  340.  355.  90336600     355.    -0.0218 
 5 TSLA   2022-01-07  360.  360.  337.  342.  84164700     342.    -0.0361 
 6 TSLA   2022-01-10  333.  353.  327.  353.  91815000     353.     0.0299 
 7 TSLA   2022-01-11  351.  359.  346.  355.  66063300     355.     0.00592
 8 TSLA   2022-01-12  360.  372.  358.  369.  83739000     369.     0.0385 
 9 TSLA   2022-01-13  370.  372.  342.  344.  97209900     344.    -0.0699 
10 TSLA   2022-01-14  340.  351.  338.  350.  72924300     350.     0.0173 
# … with 998 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Plotting

```
log_return %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  aes(x = date, y = log_returns, col = symbol) + 
  geom_line() + 
  facet_wrap(~ symbol) + 
  theme_tq()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! You provided more things for me to learn.